# Convert a html table into an rss feed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table similar to the one below which I would like to convert into an rss feed somehow. What is the best way to approach this? Should I be scraping the contents and trying to build up an rss or is there a much simpler annd easier way (I'm hoping)? I'm using the asp.net / c# - anyone point me to any tutorials out there that will help me achieve this would be great:)

```
<table align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 125px; height: 125px;" colspan="1"><img title="Costa Rica" alt="Costa Rica" src="/CR_sq.jpg?n=4185" /></td>
<td align="left" valign="top" colspan="1"><strong><font color="#fff" size="2">Costa Rica <br /></font><span class="SubHeadingGrey_7_0">16 August 2012</span></strong><br /><br />Some Text Here <a title="...read on" href="/WorkArea/linkit.aspx?LinkIdentifier=id&amp;ItemID=1234">...read on</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 125px; height: 125px;"><img width="117" height="117" title="South Africa" style="width: 117px; height: 117px;" alt="AL 2012 Icon" src="/SA2012.jpg?width=117&amp;height=117&amp;mode=max" /></td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><p><strong><font color="#fff" size="2">South African Story<br /></font><span class="SubHeadingGrey_7_0">16 August 2012</span></strong></p>
<p>This is summary text <a title="... read on" href="/SA.aspx">... read on</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" style="width: 125px; height: 125px;"><img title="ITALY" alt="ITALY" src="/Italy.jpg?n=43" /></td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><strong><font color="#fff" size="2">Italian Article<br /></font><span class="SubHeadingGrey_7_0">15 August 2012</span></strong><br /><br />Italian Visit Article<a title="...read on" href="/WorkArea/linkit.aspx?LinkIdentifier=id&amp;ItemID=1256">...read on</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use HtmlAgilityPack + XDocument to build a feed

Answer (score 1):

As long as the html is well formed and matches XML you can read it in as xml and then use XSLT to convert it to an rss feed using XslTransform  here is a simple example of how to use xlsTransform http://www.xmlfiles.com/articles/cynthia/xslt/default.asp

Comment: Thanmks I'll look into this, XSLT looks well daunting, getting my head around .net and c# :)

Comment: XSLT isn't bad and there are a number of tools that will let you take an xml file and then process it with an XLST template